# Remove or change tab's console icon in ConEmu

Tags: conemu

I'm using [ConEmu](https://conemu.github.io/), Is there any way to remove, or change, tab's console icon?

I didn't find any related option.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution, it was so simple!

In the Settings window and under `Startup -> Tasks` select the task which you wish to change its icon, then in right side, in `Task parameters` textbox set your fav. icon with `/icon` switch, e.g:

```
/icon "C:\my-very-nice-cmd-icon.ico"
```

And if you want to remove the icon, something like `/icon "-"` will do the job.

[image: ConEmu Settings Window]